# Django import-export how to handle blank Charfield

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm trying to import some data with django import-export module.
I'm having a problem and can't find any solutions to it despite the fact that it seems to be a very basic use of the import...

I'm trying to import some CharFields. These fields are not mendatory and as recommended by Django community, they are defined with blank=True in my model but not null=True.

Example:

```
description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True )
```

The problem is simple: When I try to import this field with an empty value, I get the error "NOT NULL constraint failed" on that field.

I don't understand how to solve this. Should I add null=True even if it's not usually recommended? Is there an option I don't know about?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: so you add null=True also

Answer (score 2):

As you say, the Django docs state that you should [avoid setting null on CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null).

`django-import-export` should correctly handle persisting an empty string.  However, we have seen that when importing from Excel, empty cells can be treated as `None`.

To get around this, you can declare a `Field` and add a default empty string and this should mean that Null / empty values are persisted as empty strings:

```py
# adding 'default' will force empty values to be persisted as empty strings
book_id = fields.Field(attribute="book_id", column_name="id",
            widget=widgets.CharWidget(), default="")
```

Comment: blank=True doesn't avoid having the constraint in database. I just checked, and all my not mandatory CharFields have the constraint NOT NULL in database. The null parameter is the only one that changes anything to the db constraint. To bypass the issue for now i added the space character in my import for every empty description field, but I think django-import-export is not handling this situation correctly

Comment: I checked the `django-import-export` [test app](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/tree/master/tests) and it works fine for this case.  Can you step through the code to find out what's going?  [Here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/fields.py#L66) is the line to check.  Ensure Field's `empty_values`, `widget` and `default` values are not being overridden somewhere.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I'm not familiar with breakpoints or other debug methods in python. When I have to debug my own code i just do prints. I don't know how to check how a line that is not in my code works...

Comment: It's fairly straightforward to setup up debugging and it will save you a ton of time in the long run.  I suggest download PyCharm and watch some YouTube tutorials.  Ping me offline if you want some guidance.